# Estou com dificuldade em criar um programa que busca informação no dicionário

Tags: python

O meu problema é o seguinte , estou com um dicionário , e gostaria de perguntar para o usuário qual o município que ele mora , e quando ele respondesse o programa irá procurar no dicionário aquele município digitado e vai mostrar qual a quantidade de população daquele bairro 'já está neste dicionário'
o dicionário está assim --> exemplo :

```
casas = {'São paulo':' 12.396,372',
        'Rio de janeiro':'6.775,561'}
```

obrigado !

tentei destas formas

```
def lugares2(c):
    if c in casas.keys():
        print(c, end = '')
        for v  in casas.values():
            print(v)
```

```
def lugares(m):
    pos=0
    for k in municipios.keys():
        if m in municipios:
            for v in municipios.items():
                print(v[pos])
```

Comment: acabei de resolver da seguinte forma ` 
        def lugares2(c):                                                                                                                                    
        if c in casas.keys():
        print(c , end = ' ')
        if c in casas:
            print(casas.get (c)) `

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Veja se esse exemplo ajuda https://ideone.com/YHB8LH

Comment: Qual seria o outpot que você gostaria de ter?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem?

Então, acredito que exista uma forma ainda mais simples de resolver o seu problema, sem envolver laços de repetição.

Se eu entendi corretamente, ao achar "São Paulo", você gostaria de mostrar a string "12.396,372". Correto?

Acredito que você pensou nessa implementação, pois caso a cidade não exista, acessar com `cidades['Sao Paulo']` gera uma exceção, e você não quer isso. Mas existem duas formas de tratar esse seu problema:

## Usando a função get()

Ao inves de escrever `cidades['Sao Paulo']`, é possível escrever `cidades.get('Sao Paulo', None)`, que faz a mesma coisa, só que já tratando o caso onde 'Sao Paulo' não é uma chave no dicionário (nesse caso, a função retorna None).

Então, você pode fazer algo como:

```
populacao = cidades.get(cidade_procurada, None)
if populacao != None:
    print(cidade_procurada, populacao)
```

e pode também construir sua própria lógica para caso populacao seja None (printar algo como "Não existe a cidade que voce digitou" ou algo do tipo)

## Tratando a exceção

Essa solução é um pouquinho mais técnica (não tanto assim), mas ainda vale ao menos o conhecimento de que isso existe e é possível.

Quando você tentar acessar uma chave do dicionário que não existe, o python gera uma exceção do tipo "KeyError". Então, você pode escrever um código como:

```
try:
    print(entrada, cidades[entrada])
except KeyError:
    print("Cidade não encontrada")
```

A instrução "try" executa o código contido nela, e ao inves de finalizar a execução quando encontrar um erro, ela pula para o bloco except e o executa. Caso exista mais código após try, ele executará normalmente.

Ambos os casos removem a necessidade de uma busca manual pelo dicionário, com o intuito de evitar a exceção gerada.

Espero ter compreendido corretamente seu questionamento e  conseguido tirar suas dúvidas.

Abraços!

Comment: muito obrigado !!! me ajudou demais.